# how to show input field on click of a icon in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm new to `ionic` please help me to procceed.

i have a problem, i want to show input `text field` `onclick` of `search icon`? how can i do it.   demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nxnfcl?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

**below image demonstrate my problem**

[image]

**here is my code online demo please edit:**  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nxnfcl?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar >
    <ion-title>Messages</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons right>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form>
   <ion-navbar color="primary">

    <ion-buttons left start>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>

     <ion-buttons left>
        <button ion-button icon-only style="margin-left:100%">
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>


    <ion-buttons>
        <button ion-button icon-only ion-col>
          <ion-icon name="chatboxes"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-buttons right>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>


    <ion-buttons right end>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
   </ion-navbar>
  </form> 
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first of all you add a click listener to your search icon like this:

```
<button (click)="clickedSearchIcon($event)" ion-button icon-only style="margin-left:100%">
  <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Then you create the corresponding method in your `home.ts`:

```
clickedSearchIcon(event: Event) {
  this.showSearchBar = !this.showSearchBar;
}
```

The method just flips a variable which indicates if the searchbar is shown or not. Add this variable like this:

```
export class HomePage {
 public showSearchBar = false;
 ...
```

Then you have to add the search bar you want to show in your template and use a `ngIf` directive to show and hide it when you click on the icon:

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="showSearchBar" [(ngModel)]="myInput" [showCancelButton]="false">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Don't forget to add the ngModel variable `myInput`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-p5b2rx) is an updated version of your stackblitz example.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! If it solved your question please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this

    Home.ts
    export class HomePage {

     public defaultInputBox: boolean = false;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      }

      showInputBox(){
        this.defaultInputBox = true;
      }

    In Home.html

<ion-buttons left>
        <button type="button" ion-button icon-only style="margin-left:100%" (click)="showInputBox();">
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>


    <div *ngIf="defaultInputBox">
      <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Todo</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text"  name="title"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
    </div>
```